# will not javascript exec stops when a match found?

Tags: javascript, regex

See below code

```
var re = new RegExp("j.*t");
var str = "javascript is not java and script. javascript is just javascript";

var execresult = re.exec(str);
console.log(execresult);

var matchresult = str.match(re);
console.log(matchresult);
```

both returns

```
["javascript is not java and script. javascript is just javascript"]
```

My expectation is it would return first matching text "javascript" alone, but the entire sentence is found as a match. why? is that how exec works?

I am executing this in jsbin.com, if that matters.

Comment: Try with `j.*?t` and ask again!

Comment: `.*` is matching everything between the first `j` and the last `t`.

Comment: No, the RegEx you specified captures the entire thing.   It's not a Javascript thing, just a RegEx thing.   You can see here:   http://rubular.com/r/iXXkrL3uZp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the greediness!

```
j.*?t
```

The extra mark is requesting to grab as little as possible.

Answer (score 0):

To capture each of the values that the expression can, I would recommend this:

```
(j.*?t)
```

You can see in the demo here - **[DEMO](http://rubular.com/r/9rvTWpxrxj)** - that 5 results are returned.

- javascript
- java and script
- javascript
- just
- javascript